# PDF Font Addition by manipulating BLOB/Byte[]

Tags: pdf, fonts

The job is simple - embed a font in an existing PDF.

Well not so simple - ie without using any libraries/programs -> just by editing the PDF directly, ie blob/bytes.

I am expecting some splicing etc...

But could it be done? Appreciate helpful pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The font in the PDF may well have its own custom encoding which you would have to analyse and use. Even before that, the PDF is a data dump of objects so you will need to be able to take these apart and rebuild. So it is far from simple....